# Docker can't see file created it by Laravel

Tags: linux, laravel, docker

I hosted Docker on Linux machine, Docker run Laravel project

I need to store file in `var/log`, I will check if `var/log` contain `logBackups` folder or not, I will create `logBackups` folder if it not exists, then I store file inside the `logBackups` folder. Final path will be `var/log/logBackups/myfile.zip`

From the code I see the files inside `logBackups` folder, but I can't see the files from Docker itself, I go to `var/log` then write `ls` to list the files but the folder not exists, I can't find the files.

If I search using `find -iname myFile*.zip` in the root folder of hosted machine I will find the files under 
`./var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/6ce08dbaede64ed42b8e44c0bd9ec60ee6c5843a8c4ecc977aaacb4af7ffddee/var/log/logBackups/myfile.zip`
and under 
`./var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/6ce08dbaede64ed42b8e44c0bd9ec60ee6c5843a8c4ecc977aaacb4af7ffddee/var/log/logBackups/myfile.zip`

It seems the Laravel project code use session when store data under `/var/log`

How can I find my files from Docker itself and force laravel project to use same folder Docker see?

Command used to run the project is `docker-compose -p projectname up -d`

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sendmail libmcrypt-dev libpng-dev git-all zlib1g-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt zip pdo_mysql opcache

#Speed PHP
RUN echo "file_uploads = On\n" \
         "memory_limit = 1024M\n" \
         "upload_max_filesize = 50M\n" \
         "post_max_size = 50M\n" \
         "max_execution_time = 600\n" \
         > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini


ADD dockerscriptetchosts.sh /home/dockerscriptetchosts.sh

RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
RUN php composer-setup.php
RUN php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

WORKDIR /var/www
ADD . /var/www

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/log
```

Docker-compose yml File

```
version: '2'
services:
    web:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: web.docker
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        ports:
            - "9080:80"
        links:
            - app
    app:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: app.docker
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - /var/log:/var/www/shared_log
        environment:
            - "APP_ENV=local"
```

Comment: Please add the `Dockerfile` and the command used to run the docker container, and if you have a `docker-compoose.yml` file add it to.

Comment: i added yml file and command run the docker

Comment: We also need the `Dockerfile` to be able to help you.

Comment: i add docker file, thank you @Exadra37

Comment: I see this script `dockerscriptetchosts.sh` in your `Dockerfile`... what is it doing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly read content produced by the container in the host system, you need to use a bind-mounted volume to mount a host directory into the container.  You should never directly access content in `/var/lib/docker`: it's a complex installation-specific format, and if you get it wrong you can corrupt the filesystem in your container or across all of Docker.

The `docker-compose.yml` file you show mounts the host's `/var/log` directory on to a subdirectory of the application directory; this is a little unusual and probably isn't what you want.  You want a `volumes:` declaration more like

```
volumes:
  - ./webLog:/var/log
```